# Problematic solution related to finding the function range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

> The Question: Find the range of the following function
>
> $$y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}$$

> Solution $-1.$ (the solution given to me)
>
> By Cauchy inequality,
>
> $$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≥2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=4$$  where $x>0$  $$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≤-2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=-4$$  where $x<0$ which implies $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty).$

---

But, as far as I know, we don't define inequality of arithmetic and geometric means for negative numbers.For this reason, I strange this mathematical way.

$$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≤-2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=-4$$  where $x<0.$

Okay, If our equation were equal to a

$$y=\dfrac{x-2}{2}+\dfrac{8}{2-x}$$  or $$ y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{|x|}$$ then we can not apply,

$$y=\dfrac{x-2}{2}+\dfrac{8}{2-x} \leq -2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x-2}{2}× \dfrac{8}{2-x}} \in {\emptyset}.$$

$$ y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{|x|} ≤-2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2} × \dfrac{8}{|x|}} \in {\emptyset}.$$  where $x<0$.

What I mean,

For $x<0$ ,the arithmetic meaning of $\dfrac{\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}}2$  doesn't exist and the geometric meaning of $\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}$ doesn't exist.

So, for $x<0$ to write the $\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}$,  I think, it doesn't make sense.

I would go on like this.

$$y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≥2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=4$$  where $x>0$

Then, for $x<0$ we have both $\dfrac{x}{2}$ and $\dfrac{8}{x}$ are negative. In this sense we can write

$$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≥2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=4$$

$$-\left(\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}\right)\leq-4$$

$$- \dfrac{x}{2}+\left(-\dfrac{8}{x}\right) \leq-4$$ where $x>0$.

It seems more sense to me.

So we get, $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$

I don't know how right I am.

> My solution:
>
> $$\begin{align} y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x} \Longrightarrow 2yx=x^2+16 \Longrightarrow x^2-2yx+16=0 \Longrightarrow \Delta=y^2-16 \geq0 \Longrightarrow y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty). \end{align}$$

- Question $-1$ :Do you find the solution $-1$ perfect?
- Question$-2$ :Is my own solution correct?

**Remark.**

> If our function were as follows, we could easily apply the arithmetic-geometric inequality.
>
> $$y=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x^2}$$
>
> $$y=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x^2}≥2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x^2}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x^2}}=4$$
>
> $$y \in [4, +\infty)$$

Comment: Since in case two $x $ is neagtive, how about writing the inequality with $-x$,since $-x$ is positive in this case, so this will yield the reasult

Comment: By plotting your function, I get also $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Question $-1$ :Do you find the solution $-1$ perfect?

No, I don't.

Firstly, the inequality in solution $-1$ is correct.

If $x\lt 0$, then by the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, we have
$$\frac x2+\frac 8x=-\bigg(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac{8}{-x}\bigg)\le -2\sqrt{\frac{-x}{2}\times\frac{8}{-x}}=-4$$

So, the inequality in solution $-1$ is correct.

Secondly, however, solution $-1$ is not correct because it does not prove that the range is $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$. Solution $-1$ proves that if $x\gt 0$, then $y\ge 4$, and if $x\lt 0$, then $y\le -4$. This does not imply that the range is $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$. Solution $-1$ does not prove that $y$ can take every value in $(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$.

> - Question$-2$ :Is my own solution correct?

Yes, it is.

(I would add some words as follows : $y=\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}$ is equivalent to $x^2-2yx+16=0$. There is at least one $x$ satisfying this quadratic equation on $x$ if and only if the discriminant is non-negative, i.e. $y \in(-\infty, -4] ∪ [4, +\infty)$.)

Comment: (+) Thank you.  1)On the other hand
$$\dfrac{x}{2}+\dfrac{8}{x}≤-2\sqrt{ \dfrac{x}{2}× \dfrac{8}{x}}=-4$$  where $x<0.$  this inequality is not the same with your inequality $\frac x2+\frac 8x=-\bigg(\frac{-x}{2}+\frac{8}{-x}\bigg)\le -2\sqrt{\frac{-x}{2}\times\frac{8}{-x}}=-4$. where, $x<0.$  Because, multiplying two negative numbers under the root makes no sense (to me).  This implies that the Cauchy is can used for negative numbers.But this is achieved only by manipulating arithmetic-geometric inequality.  Therefore, I have cited 2 examples that this inequality is not applicable directly.

Comment: 2) Does your answer imply my "Remark" is also wrong?

Comment: @Elementary : 1) You are right. I should have mentioned that the inequality I wrote is not the same as the one in solution $-1$. 2) You've proved that $y\ge 4$ for any $x$. But  if you are trying to find the range, note that you have not proved that the range is $y\in [4,+\infty)$ since you have not proved that $y$ can take every value in $[4,+\infty)$.

Comment: 1) I understood. 2) I must say I'm really surprised.  An interesting fact.  I never thought so.

Comment: @Elementary : 2) You can prove that the range is $y\in [4,+\infty)$ using discriminant as follows : $y=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{8}{x^2}$ is equivalent to $(x^2)^2-2yx^2+16=0$ which is a quadratic equation on $x^2$. This has at least one *positive* $x^2$ if and only if $y\gt 0$ and $y^2-16\ge 0$, i.e. $y\in [4,+\infty)$. The condition $y\gt 0$ comes from that the axis of the parabola has to be positive.

Comment: 2) Thank you for your explanation.. I always use your discriminant method.....By the way, I don't want to keep you busy.. but I succumb to my sense of curiosity. But,  can we really find a counterexample for this?  Cauchy gives us $ y≥4 $ or $y≤-4$ , but the range of function is not really $ (- \infty, 4] $. or $[4,\infty) $    (or any $ y≥ \alpha $ and $y≤-\alpha$)

Comment: @Elementary : An interesting and natural question:) How about $y=\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}$ ? We have $y\ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2+2}{x^2+1}\times\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}}=2$, but the range is $y\in (2,\frac 52]$ according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2B2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2B%28x%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2%29).

Comment: You are a great thinker/mathematician.  This is the most interesting fact I've learned for years! Endless thanks for the great information!This counterexample is truly fascinating!Although I don't know how you found it!I'm shocked right now. Curious facts for someone who is not equipped like me.

Comment: @Elementary : You are welcome:) I've considered the examples of the form $y=f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}$ satisfying $f(x)\gt 0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)\color{red}{\not=}+\infty$. If we can get such an example, then its range should be something like $y\in [2,C)$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes, I understood the meat of your idea now.:) 
 $\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2}=1$ In this sense we can also write $y=\dfrac{x^4+10}{x^4+20}+\dfrac{x^4+20}{x^4+10}$ isn't it ?

Comment: Finally, you took the time to teach me.  Thank you very very much.  You are a real educator/pedagogue.

Comment: @Elementary : Yes, $y=\dfrac{x^4+10}{x^4+20}+\dfrac{x^4+20}{x^4+10}$ is also a counterexmaple whose range is, interestingly enough, $y\in (2,\frac 52]$. You are welcome. I enjoyed finding counterexameples.

Comment: I've realized now. $"y"$  again gives the same range interestingly. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

y' = 1/2 - 8/x$^2$
Solving y' = 0, x$^2$ = 16.
Thus for positive x,
the minimum of y is y(4) = 4
and the range of y is [4,$\infty$).
Simular for negative x.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve my questions.

Comment: @Elementary It solves the problem and shows you are solving the problem in a very hard and useless way.